# Does `git rebase master` really mean `git rebase-myself-onto master`?

Tags: git

I had a hard time fully understanding `git rebase` at first, because I didn't know what the word "rebase" as a verb mean.

Later on it seems it means "change the base of something from A to B".

So when we do

```
git checkout foo
git rebase master
```

so the words "rebase master" doesn't actually mean "rebase the master branch"?  It actually means "rebase the current branch to use master as a base"?  So it actually means

```
git checkout foo
git rebase-myself-onto master
```

?  It is to take the whole branch of `foo` and make it "based" on master, isn't it?

Comment: You're right, you rebase "on to" the target argument—foo onto master, in this case. Note that `git rebase`'s argument, `master` in this case, actually has *two* roles. Sometimes you need two separate arguments and then you will use `git rebase --onto <target> <upstream>`. Currently, the one argument `master` is fulfilling both roles: target, and what the rebase documentation calls *`upstream`*.

Comment: There's a key underlying concept here called *reachability*, because commits are very often on more than one branch all at the same time. For (much) more on reachability, see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).

Answer (score 2):

In your first example:

```
git checkout foo
git rebase master
```

the rebase command can be read as "place my commits in the `foo` branch, since I first branched off `master`, onto a new base, that new base being the current HEAD commit of the `master` branch."

That is, no, you are not rebasing `master`, but rather telling Git to replay your latest commits in the `foo` branch on top of the latest `master` branch.

A picture is worth a thousand words when dealing with Git workflow concepts.  Consider a scenario before rebasing:

```
master: A -- B -- C
              \
foo:            D -- E
```

And here is what this looks like after `git rebase master`:

```
master: A -- B -- C
                   \
foo:                D' -- E'
```

You can clearly see that your `D` and `E` commits are now sitting on a new *base* (the reason why the command is called re-base).  That new base is the HEAD of the current `master` branch, which also means that your updated `foo` branch now has all the latest commits which might have come into `master` since you initially branched.  Also note that I labelled the `D'` and `E'` commits with an apostrophe.  This is because when Git reapplies your commits on top of the new base, it actually creates *new* commits (which, however, are likely to be functionally very similar to the original ones, assuming you did not have conflicts and make very big changes).

Comment: then does `git rebase master` means `git rebase-myself-onto master`? (if we think of `master` being the tip of the `master` branch)

Comment: Well if you want to want use actual `onto` syntax, the above would be `git rebase --onto master B`.

Comment: Is `git rebase --onto master B` exactly the same as `git rebase master B`?  And my question really is about what "rebase" means and about `rebase master` sounding weird, because you are not rebasing `master`; you are rebasing the current branch.

Comment: No, they're _not_ the same.  The first one means replay the `D --- E` commits on top of the `master` `C` commit.  I'm not familiar with the syntax of your second option.  I have addressed the language nuances already in my answer.

Comment: `git rebase --onto master B` and `git rebase master` are the same thing.

Comment: wait, your second version doesn't have `B`.  `git rebase master B` simply means, if you are on `B`, and you are doing `git rebase master`

Comment: `git rebase master B` means you don't have to `git checkout B` first before you do `git rebase master`. You can be on any branch at all, and do `git rebase master B` and the result is always the same no matter what branch you are on

Answer (score 0):

The full command is *[git rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) upstream-branch target-branch*.
If target-branch is specified, git rebase will perform an automatic *git checkout target-branch* before doing anything else. **Otherwise it remains on the current branch**.

So, when you use command *git rebase master*, it means rebase current branch(foo) upon upstream branch(branch master).
Actually you can simply use *git rebase master foo* to achieve the same result for:
git checkout foo
git rebase master